# How to update MySQL table from another table with some condition

Tags: mysql

I've TABLE-A with following structure:

```
id      step1error          step2error          step3error
1       null                {json:"string"}     null
2       {json:"error1"}     {json:"error2"}     {json:"error3"}
```

And TABLE-B with following structure:

```
id      ref(of TABLE-A)     error
1       1                   null
2       2                   null
3       2                   null
3       2                   null
```

I tried following query, but it always update TABLE-B with step1error from TABLE-A. 
Query:

```
SET @exist = (select count(TABLE-B.id) from TABLE-B left join TABLE-A on TABLE-B.ref = TABLE-A.id where 
 TABLE-B.error =  TABLE-A.step2error);
UPDATE `TABLE-B` inner join VIEW-AB on TABLE-B.ref=VIEW-AB.ref 
SET TABLE-B.error = 
    CASE 
        WHEN VIEW-AB.step1error != 'null' THEN VIEW-AB.step1error
        WHEN VIEW-AB.step2error != 'null' THEN VIEW-AB.step2error
        ELSE VIEW-AB.step3error END 
WHERE 
TABLE-B.error = 'null' and 
TABLE-B.id = VIEW-AB.B_ref and 
 @exist = 0;
```

VIEW-AB

```
create view VIEW-AB as (SELECT  TABLE-B.id "B_ref", TABLE-A.step1error , TABLE-A.step2error, TABLE-A.step3error FROM `TABLE-B` left join TABLE-A on TABLE-B.ref= TABLE-A.id WHERE TABLE-B.error = 'null');
```

VIEW-AB looks like:

```
B_ref   ref(TABLE-A)    step1error          step2error          step3error
1       1               null              {json:"string"}      null
2       2               {json:"error1"}   {json:"error2"}      {json:"error3"}
3       2               {json:"error1"}   {json:"error2"}      {json:"error3"}
3       2               {json:"error1"}   {json:"error2"}      {json:"error3"}
```

My Result:

```
id      ref(of TABLE-A)     error
1       1                   {json:"string"}
2       2                   {json:"error1"}
3       2                   {json:"error1"}
3       2                   {json:"error1"}
```

I need to write a MySQL query to update TABLE-B (where error is null) in such way that it looks like bellow:

Expected Result:

```
id      ref(of TABLE-A)     error
1       1                   {json:"string"}
2       2                   {json:"error1"}
3       2                   {json:"error2"}
3       2                   {json:"error3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your null check in your case statement. Instead of `'null'` use `null` directly.

Hence mysql consider `'null'` as string.

use below query

```
SET @exist = (select count(TABLE-B.id) from TABLE-B left join TABLE-A on TABLE-B.ref = TABLE-A.id where 
 TABLE-B.error =  TABLE-A.step2error);
UPDATE `TABLE-B` inner join VIEW-AB on TABLE-B.ref=VIEW-AB.ref 
SET TABLE-B.error = 
    CASE 
        WHEN VIEW-AB.step1error is not null THEN VIEW-AB.step1error
        WHEN VIEW-AB.step2error is not null THEN VIEW-AB.step2error
        ELSE VIEW-AB.step3error END 
WHERE 
TABLE-B.error = 'null' and 
TABLE-B.id = VIEW-AB.B_ref and 
 @exist = 0;
```

Comment: Still same. I think, I am missing something. Because this case is always executing the first case. I need to check if I've already processed the `step1error`.  I was trying to create a function that will take the `VIEW-AB.B_ref` and check if its already resolved for `step1error`. But I was unable to call the function from switch case.

Comment: Create a sample at sql fiddle and share it link. I will check it.